# How can i make my program testing goldbach hypotheis optimize in less than 5 sec

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I am a 1st year student and our professor gave us a task to check the Goldbach hypothesis in a given range. The program has to take less than 5 seconds to run, now it takes approximately 160s. I would be very glad if somebody could tell me how to make the program quicker, or give some examples with a short description? Here is the program:

```
int czy_pierwsza(int);
int goldbach(int);
int czy_pierwsza(int x)
{
    int count=0, i;
    if(x<2) return 0;
    for(i=2; i<x-1; i++)
    {  if((x%i)==0) count++;}
    if(count==0)
    return 1;
    else
    return 0;
}
int goldbach(int x)
{int i, y, a=0, tab[2000];
    for(i=2; i<x-1; i++)
    {if(czy_pierwsza(i)==1)
        {
            for(y=2; y<x-1; y++)
            {if(czy_pierwsza(y)==1){
                    if(y+i==x) {  tab[a]=i; tab[a+1]=y;  a+=2; }}}}
        y=a;
    }for(a=0; a<y; a+=2) {printf("(%d %d)", tab[a], tab[a+1]);}
    if(a!=0) return 1; else return 0;
}


int main()
{
    int a=1400, b=1600, x;

    if(a>b) {printf("Incorrect input"); return 1;}
    if(a%2!=0) a+=1;

    for(x=a; x<b+1; x+=2){
        {printf("%d: ", x);
            if(goldbach(x)==1){  printf("\n");}
            else printf("\n");}}


    return 0;
```

Comment: `if((x%i)==0) count++;` when you're counting the divisors you could just go up to sqrt(x) and count twice (with the "opposite" divisor unless the divisor is the exact square root). that cuts the complexity of counting the divisors: `if (x%i)==0 { count++; if (i*i!=x) count++;}`

Comment: You might find that [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a better site to discuss working code.

Comment: also why are you counting the divisors when you just need to know if the number is prime? use a prime number checker instead (sieve of erathostenes) or test divisors up to sqrt(n) only

Comment: @WeatherVane code that exceeds its allocated time limit by a factor of 30 can hardly be called working.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. if it produced the correct result then it *was* working. OP is seeking to improve its performance, which is what Code Review is suitable for.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is working if it implements the spec. Producing correct results is a part of the spec, not the entire spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the culprit is (as usual) a wrong prime checking function. Not that it is wrong, but it's *super slow*.

Your function `czy_pierwsza` counts the divisors, then returns 0 or 1 depending if there are divisors or not. That amounts to *check for primes* (you don't need the number of divisors, and if you need them, you could count them faster too, but that's not the point)

Rewriting with a proper prime check (there are other ways but that one doesn't need an extra array)

```
int czy_pierwsza(int x)
{
    int i;
    if(x<2) return 0;
    for(i=2; i<(int)(sqrt(x))+1; i++)
    {  if((x%i)==0) return 0;}

    return 1;
}
```

as soon as it finds a divisor, it returns 0. If it goes through the loop up to square root of the number without finding a divisor, then the number is prime and it returns 1.

Now the program runs in a few seconds on my machine.